# What Is The Best Way To Store User Details After Login?

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I Try To Develop School Management System , Each Teacher Will Be Having Its Own Role And Department And Class Her/his Belong . I Finish To Build Authentication (login And Logout ) . Using Django Restframework And Jwt The Problem I Face Is When Teacher After Login In I Want To Store His/her Profile Details Through Multiple Page So When Teacher Doing Certain Action In A Certain Model It Will Be Easy To Know A Certain Action Has Been Done By This Teacher . I Use Django And Angular 8 As Front End

Thanks.

Comment: You will not get an answer to this question here, as StackOverflow is a Q&A site for specific programming problems. There are a huge number of articles out there on how to do security in Angular and Javascript in general. There is no single "best" solution. As with everything in Javascript, don't store sensitive data in the app, and your server always has the final say in whether a user is permitted to access a resource.

Answer (score 0):

you can store user's credentials in LocalStorage of browser with an expiration date "localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'). After you set you can use 'localStorage.getItem('key', 'value') to check this user is authentificated or not.
Read more about LocalStorage I think it will help you